# Can't solve this exponential equation: $5^{x+1}-3\cdot 5^{x-1} - 6\cdot 5^x+10 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

How does one solve for $x$ in the following:

$$5^{x+1}-3\cdot 5^{x-1} - 6\cdot 5^x+10 = 0$$

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 9):

write it in the form
$$5\cdot 5^x-\frac{3}{5}\cdot 5^x-6\cdot 5^x+10=0$$ setting $5^x=t$ so you will get a linear equation

Comment: Thanks you!  So once I solve it for t, how do I find x?   Here's what I used to solve... http://s14.postimg.org/7f8irj0fl/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: wer get $$10=\frac{8}{5}t$$ thus $t=25/4$ setting for $t=5^x$ and your must use the logarithm $$5^x=25/4$$ thus $$x\ln(5)=\ln(25/4)$$

Answer (score 2):

First assume $5^x=y$ solving that equation you get $y=5^x=\frac{25}{4}$ so now $5^x=25/4$ taking log to the base $5$ you get $x=2-log_{5}(4)$ so now $log_{5}4=log_{10}4/log_{10}5\approx 0.85$ thus $x=2-0.85=1.15$ . And its done.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing both sides by $5^{x-1}$ (*this is valid since for all real numbers, $5^{x-1}$ is nonzero*) we are left with the following:

$\frac{5^{x+1}}{5^{x-1}}-3\frac{5^{x-1}}{5^{x-1}}-6\frac{5^{x}}{5^{x-1}}+10\frac{1}{5^{x-1}}=25-3-30+10\cdot 5^{1-x}=0$

Yielding the equation:

$10\cdot 5^{1-x}=8$

You can continue solving from there.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$5^{x+1}-3\cdot 5^{x-1}-6\cdot 5^x+10=0$$
$$6\cdot 5^x+3\cdot 5^{x-1}-5^{x+1}=10$$

$$5^{x-1}(6\cdot 5+3-5^2)=10$$
$$8\cdot 5^{x-1}=10$$
$$5^{x-1}=\frac{5}{4}$$
$$(x-1)\ln(5)=\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\ln(5)}+1=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)+\ln(5)}{\ln(5)}$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{blue}{x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{25}{4}\right)}{\ln(5)}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$5^{x+1}-3*5^{x-1}-6*5^x=-10$

Putting $5^x=y$,

$5y-\frac{3y}{5}-6y=-10$

Solving,we get $y=\frac{25}{4}$

Comment: What’s $t$? I think you failed to carry through a change of notation.